# MySQL query faster in DESC order than ASC order

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, innodb

I made a simple database (innodb version 5.7.9) with 2 tables, post and post_tag.

Post has a single field ID (big int) set as Primary key (about 120,000 entries).
Post_tag has 2 fields, post_id (big int) and tag_id (int), and the primary key is on [post_id, tag_id].

The following query runs in ~1ms:

```
SELECT 
   SQL_NO_CACHE p.id 
FROM 
   post as p 
STRAIGHT_JOIN 
   post_tag t
WHERE  
   t.post_id = p.id AND t.tag_id = 25 
ORDER BY 
   p.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

But if I change the ORDER BY to ASC, it runs about 100 times slower! And that the sort I am interested into...

**Any idea why?**

Initially, I wanted the IDs sorted DESC, and I noticed it was slower than ASC. I read that the natural sort for index is ASC, so I reverted all the ID (by doing ID = SOMETHING BIG - ID), but then it didn't changed anything as it's now slower in ASC.

I uploaded the database [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ck4Ob9r9LvMlN1TlJoNEtSNzA/view?usp=sharing) in case it's useful.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

And here is the explain:
[image]

Comment: Does changing `WHERE` to `ON` and just doing a regular `JOIN` instead of `STRAIGHT_JOIN` change anything?

Comment: You probably have an index created on the table or there might be a default primary key index created by default on ID column.  You can re-index it and make it to the order you want. If you query in order reverse than the order of your index the query is definitely going to run slower. Just try to re-index in the order you want to query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson changing where to ON doesn't change anything.

Doing a regular join change the execution plan to start with the post_tag table, and this is not what I want. The reason is that my actual database (what I posted here is just a stripped down example) has a more complex index key that requires to start the execution plan by the post table. And actually in this case I don't need a straight join as mysql understand that. So in just I just put the straight join to be under the same condition as my actual database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are "other constraints", then all bets are off.

Meanwhile, looking at what you have...

`STRAIGHT_JOIN`, `USE INDEX`, etc, are crutches for when (a) you don't have the 'right' index, or (b) the optimizer can't figure out the 'right' thing to do.  *That is, look for other solutions.*

In your example, you would be better of with a plain `JOIN` and `INDEX(tag_id, post_id)`.  This would let it go to `post_tag` *first* since there is a `WHERE` clause letting it filter there.  The optimizer will probably see that `t.post_id` and `p.id` are identical, so start a the end (for `DESC`) of `(25, post_id)` in the index, and scan.  It then checks to see if there is a `post` entry (that being the only apparent use for `post` -- again if there are "other constraints", all bets are off).

So, back to the original question.  `STRAIGHT_JOIN` *forced* looking in `post` first.  But where are the 25s?  Apparently near the *end* of `post_tag`.  Hence, `ASC` took longer to find 100 (see `LIMIT`) of them than if the scan started at the other end!

Assuming this is a many-to-many mapping table, do this:

```
CREATE TABLE post_tag (
    post_id ...,
    tag_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(post_id, tag_id),
    INDEX      (tag_id, post_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I discuss the many reasons in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

If, as was suggested, you add `(tag_id, post_id DESC)`, don't be deluded into thinking that the `DESC` means anything -- it is recognized, but ignored.  *Both* parts will be stored `ASC`.  What will happen is that the Optimizer is smart enough to start at the end of the 25s and scan backward.  Here's "proof":

`US` has `INDEX(state, population)`:

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
mysql> SELECT city, population FROM US
          WHERE state = 'OH'
          ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5;
+------------+------------+
| city       | population |
+------------+------------+
| Columbus   |     736836 |
| Cleveland  |     449514 |
| Toledo     |     306974 |
| Cincinnati |     306382 |
| Akron      |     208414 |
+------------+------------+
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
| Handler_read_key           | 1     |  -- get started at end of Ohio
| Handler_read_prev          | 4     |  -- read (5-1) more, scanning backwards
```

The only case where MySQL is missing the boat by ignoring `DESC` in an `INDEX` declaration is:  `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC` cannot use `INDEX(a,b)`.

Comment: You are totally right, the 25s are at the end of the list, which explains why it takes longer to execute in on order than the other. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, you have an index on `post(id)` (this is created automatically for primary keys, for instance).  MySQL sometimes pays attention to the order of the index when using an index for `ORDER BY`.

By changing the order, you are changing the query plan in such a way that sorting is necessary.

I would suggest writing the query using only one table:

```
SELECT t.post_id 
FROM post_tag t
WHERE t.tag_id = 25 
ORDER BY t.post_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The `JOIN` is not necessary for this query, assuming that all values of `post_id` refer to valid posts (which seems like a very reasonable assumption).

For this query, an index on `post_tag(tag_id, post_id desc)` is optimal, and MySQL might do the right thing for a descending sort.

Comment: As I explained, I have a primary index in post(id). 
Thanks for you suggestion, but I would like to solve the problem by understanding why it's slower in ASC than DESC, instead of changing the query. The reason is that  I can't apply your suggestion in my real database, which has other constraints.

Comment: But the query you suggest is quite interesting in the fact that  it's about 10 times faster in DESC (~1ms) than in ASC  order (~10ms). Any idea  why?

Comment: @maalls . . . That is probably just some subtle inefficiency in reading the index backwards.  The times are very small, so a difference of 10x is probably not meaningful.  Such small differences might be caused by  things like caching or look-ahead page read optimizations.

Comment: @maalls . . . You should change the query.  Getting rid of an unnecessary join is a good thing.